# magI = magI(Rect(0, 0, magI.cols & -2, magI.rows & -2));

Tags: c++, opencv

Recently I am learning how to use opencv to process image. In using the function
dft(), they presented a example. But I don't understand the following code:
    
    `magI = magI(Rect(0, 0, magI.cols & -2, magI.rows & -2));`
    
What's meaning of `&` in the code, and what's meaning of the code?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the example and/or more context to the code.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl Here is the example http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html

Comment: Thanks, I had asked because without that information one has to guess what magI is. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, your question presumably was downvoted because you didn't comply with that document. Now you already have been given a good answer so that doesn't matter anymore. Please don't forget to accept the answer: If you still have doubts you may ask questions by commenting the answer.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl  Thanks for your advice. It's the first time for me to ask a question in this website, so maybe I made a mistake. I forgot the binary usage of `&`. Next time I 'll do more research, and improve my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this for the `&` operator (bitwise and): http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

What is happening here is that an object `Rect` is created, and that is passed to magI.
The object Rect is created with an even number of cols and rows (-2 = 0xFFFFFFFE), so the least significant bit is cleared.